# AngularJs push doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, multidimensional-array, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send a Json value to the MVC webApi controller... My AngularJs controller looks like this...

```
addModule.controller('addEmployeeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

//To push the roleId and roleName into AddEmployee variable
$scope.empList = [];

//On-click function
$scope.submitChanges = function (addEmployeeData) {

    //To push the roleId and roleName into AddEmployee variable
    var roleItem =
        {
            RoleName: addEmployeeData.Role.roleName,
            RoleId: addEmployeeData.Role.roleId
        };
    $scope.empList.push(roleItem);

    //creating a variable to post to the other end
    var addEmployee = {
        UserName: addEmployeeData.UserName,
        EmployeeLastName: addEmployeeData.LastName,
        EmployeeFirstName: addEmployeeData.FirstName,
        Role: $scope.empList            
    };       


    $http.post('/api/EmployeeAPI/CreateEmployee/' , JSON.stringify(addEmployee), { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
```

When i try to send into the webApi controller, it won't grab the **Role** value in **addEmployee** variable... Always **Roles** value is null...
[image]

Comment: You are sending it as `Role` though with a missing `s`

Comment: thanks... it works now...

Comment: Ok.. marking for closure for simple typo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending Role instead of Roles

convert this

```
Role: $scope.empList
```

to this

```
Roles: $scope.empList
```